# How can I build footer in website using Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web, flutter-animation

I tried to build my footer on Flutter as in the picture below, but i can't go further. Does anyone has an idea how to fix this?
iiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii
[image: ee]

Here's my code as below. Please watch it carefully and give me any idea.

```
 Container(
              color: Colors.grey[600],
              child: Row(children: [
                const Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
                ),
                BottomAppBar(
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                    children: const [
                      Text('Escort'),
                      Text('Escort'),
                      Text('Escort'),
                      Text('Escort'),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                const Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
                ),
                BottomAppBar(
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                    children: const [
                      Text('Escort'),
                      Text('Escort'),
                      Text('Escort'),
                      Text('Escort'),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                const Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
                ),
                BottomAppBar(
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                    children: const [
                      Text('Escort'),
                      Text('Escort'),
                      Text('Escort'),
                      Text('Escort'),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                const Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
                ),
                BottomAppBar(
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                    children: const [
                      Text('Escort'),
                      Text('Escort'),
                      Text('Escort'),
                      Text('Escort'),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ]),
            )
```

[image: e]

Comment: please explain more, what is your issue and  what do you want to achive.

Comment: I want to build my footer as in my second image updated @pmatatias

Comment: please give any idea how to do it

Comment: @pmatatias .....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wrap your colum with `Expanded`

[image]

```
Container(
  color: Colors.black,
  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30, vertical: 10),
  child: Row(
    children: [
      Expanded(
          child: Column(
        children: [
          TextButton(
            onPressed: () {},
            child: const Text(
              "Text abc",
            ),
          ),
          TextButton(
            onPressed: () {},
            child: const Text("Text abc"),
          ),
          TextButton(
            onPressed: () {},
            child: const Text("Text abc"),
          ),
            TextButton(
            onPressed: () {},
            child: const Text("Text abc"),
          ),
        ],
      )),
      Expanded(
          child: Column(
        children: [
          TextButton(
            onPressed: () {},
            child: const Text(
              "Text abc",
            ),
          ),
          TextButton(
            onPressed: () {},
            child: const Text("Text abc"),
          ),
        ],
      )),
      Expanded(
          child: Column(
        children: [
          TextButton(
            onPressed: () {},
            child: const Text(
              "Text abc",
            ),
          ),
          TextButton(
            onPressed: () {},
            child: const Text("Text abc"),
          ),
          TextButton(
            onPressed: () {},
            child: const Text("Text abc"),
          ),
        ],
      )),
      Expanded(
          child: Column(
        children: const [Text("Newsletter widget", style:TextStyle(color:Colors.white))],
      )),
    ],
  )),
```

Comment: Now it's better. Thanks @pmatatias

Answer (score 0):

You can use  `LimittedBox()` and then pass the required height and width this will solve your problem. You can also use `MediaQuery` to get screen size.